# Nodejs and Node show two different versions. How can this be?

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

I've been all over looking for a solution. I've read that I should purge both node and nodejs, do a fresh installation then link the two together. This did not work. I was told to try nodejs legacy. This did not work.

I am trying to install something that requires a newer version of node. My nodejs has upgraded just fine, but node, unfortunately, has not.

```
node -v
v5.4.1

nodejs -v
v8.**** (latest)
```

I can't be the only person who is experiencing this. Does anyone have a fix? Running Ubuntu 16.04

```
fappycow@fappycow-desktop:~$ type -a node nodejs 
node is /home/fappycow/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.1/bin/node 
node is /usr/local/bin/node 
node is /usr/bin/node 
nodejs is /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: Output of `type -a node nodejs`, please.

Comment: `fappycow@fappycow-desktop:~$ type -a node nodejs
node is /home/fappycow/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.1/bin/node
node is /usr/local/bin/node
node is /usr/bin/node
nodejs is /usr/bin/nodejs
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that node has been installed with nvm. Whenever you want to upgrade to the latest version of `node`, just run `nvm install node`.

I would also uninstall `nodejs`: `sudo apt purge nodejs`

Using nvm is much better than the nodejs binary.

Comment: How tf do you guys just know this? I've seriously been searching and searching. I saw a nvm solution but they were saying you had to cd into a location(which I didnt have) and then purge it and then reinstall it with make etc. Thank you for this! I hope it helps someone else too

Comment: I had heaps of problems installing node until I found nvm. BTW: If this answer helped you click the tick next to it to mark it as the correct answer. It will give us both more reputation.

Comment: What is crazy though is I opened another terminal and typed in node -v and I got the previous version again which messed up the next step in my installation process for solidity.

Comment: Check it out its wild I have no idea whats going on here: http://imgur.com/a/9obZ7

Comment: An answer to the first screenshot. `nvm` can only be run by your own user. `sudo` runs it as the root user. You should never have to run `nvm` as root.

Comment: For the second screenshot, what is the output of `nvm ls`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60737/discussion-between-fappycow-and-yamboy1).